# Mavericks Server: Unable to use 3rd party SSL Certificates with Open Directory

Tags: macos, osx-server, certificate, ssl, open-directory

We have a Mac OS X Server (Mavericks) - `Mac OS X: 10.9.2`,  `Server: 3.1`

Our Open Directory Master is set up and running but we cannot for the life of us get it to accept our 3rd Party (DigiCert) SSL certificate. The certificate is active for all other services (Mail, Calendar, WWW, Messages) but whenever I select it for Open Directory and click `OK` the Server app just reverts back to "None".

I've tried destroying the OD Master and rebuilding it but this didn't help; problem persists.

This seems like a show stopper; anyone know how we can fix this?

Comment: The same thing for me, but with a web server.
If I set 3rd party certificate via website settings panel there is some diagnostic in Console log:
`Error: The server '127.0.0.1' reported an error while processing a command of type: 'writeSettings' in plug-in: 'servermgr_web'. Error: Error Domain=XSActionErrorDomain Code=0 "Error Domain=XSServerFoundationErrorDomain Code=11 "Attempt to modify read-only settings on default virtual host" ...`

Answer (score 1):

I believe Apple fixed that bug in Server 4 but I can't reproduce it on Server 5. Have you checked the `serveradmin` command line tool to check your settings and status:

```
sudo serveradmin fullstatus dirserv
sudo serveradmin settings dirserv
sudo serveradmin -x settings certs
```

The -x argument instructs serveradmin to format the data as XML, which often shows more information (at least in the case of certs).

Sometimes you can set things there that the GUI balks at - but you also want to have the ability to call AppleCare for support or a great backup plan that's tested before mucking with sudo and serveradmin from my experience.